# Java Applets crash after upgrade to runtime 1.7u65 update 65

Tags: java, javascript, applet, java-7

The most recent Java Update 65 that Oracle has pushed with auto-update seems to be crashing Java Applets in all the Windows browsers.

I tested and reproduced the problem with a number of Windows 7 machines, the one I'm using right now has Service Pack 1. The symptoms are the same in all the web browsers, IE, Chrome, FF Java Applets just don't load in the web browser. In Firefox I can see a black box instead of the Applet. In other browsers it's just a white screen.

You can try the applets here: http://www.utechsoft.com/products/unlimitedftp/

These demos were corrected when Java 1.7 update 45 came out and all were working before update 65.

These demos use deployJava.js from Oracle's website: http://java.com/js/deployJava.js

Anyone is hitting similar issues?

Strangely, our other applet at http://www.utechsoft.com/products/uupload/ UUpload Professional is working fine with update 65. What did Oracle change in the most recent update 65 that could cause this problem?

Yes I work for Unlimi-Tech Software.

Comment: I test with lastest firefox & chrome and it works fine (Windows 8.1). Here is my Java version: Java Plug-in 10.65.2.19, Using JRE version 1.7.0_65-b19 Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM. Its better to share your console log for the java plugin.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Issues with Java 7u65](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24792360/issues-with-java-7u65)

Comment: Yes this is similar to the other question. However the fix of Changing 'java_arguments' to 'java-vm-args' does NOT work for Java Applets. It only fixes Web Start. The only fix for applets right now is to completely remove 'java_arguments' parameter.

Comment: The problem is inside the deployment.properties. The right answer is http://stackoverflow.com/a/24815238/12631

Answer (score 0):

Is the one crashing using the VM arguments? I ran any of the 2, I saw :

```
security:  --- parseCommandLine converted : -Xmx512m -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack:true
into: [-Xmx512m, -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack:true]
```

and another one is without.